# Some characters not displayed on the Eclipse console with println()

Tags: java, string, eclipse, stringbuffer

I came across a strange problem recently. I am using `StringBuffer` to create a string and when I added some white spaces to the string, I realized that some characters were gone.

**An example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    sb.append("000.00                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ");
    sb.append(filler(800));
    sb.append(filler(800));
    sb.append(filler(800));
    sb.append(filler(800));
    sb.append(filler(800));

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    System.out.println(sb.toString().charAt(4));

}

public static String filler(Integer size) {
    return String.join("", Collections.nCopies(size, " "));
}
```

**Output running in Eclipse**:

```
000.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
0
```

`filler` is a function to create blank strings.

When I run that, the last two zeros of my initial string simple disappears. The curious is that if I print the value of the position in those positions, the zero appears.

Is that some kind of bug on StringBuffer class?

Comment: It's probably truncated by your IDE. Also, your snippet doesn't compile.

Comment: What does `filler()` actually do?  Create a string with `size` number of spaces?

Comment: @markspace yes, it is to fill a string with a certain amount of spaces.

Comment: your initial string is fully shown, where's the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I copy/pasted what you posted and it works fine for me in Eclipse.

Comment: I didn't understand why those downvotes. How could I improve my question? :)

Comment: @Alexandre Miziara Your question is not bad at all (I voted for) . But as according to the used IDEs the result is not necessary the same, it was downvoted by some that didn't understand the interest of your question I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a **rendering** problem probably specific to your IDE as you output a  `String` with a relative important number of characters.

If I run your program on Eclipse I **see** indeed an unexpected output :

```
000.
```

While I expected `000.00` as beginning of the line.

But if I copy the beginning of the line produced in the Eclipse console and I paste it somewhere else, I see the expected output :

```
000.00
```

Make a substring of the `StringBuilder` and you could see an accurate visible output :

```
System.out.println(sb.substring(0,6));
```

---

For information the problem occurs only at the last `append()` :

```
    sb.append(filler(800));
    sb.append(filler(800));
    sb.append(filler(800));
    sb.append(filler(800));
    sb.append(filler(800)); // issue in the output from there
```

---

Note that you can force in the Eclipse preferences the **maximum character width**. It will cause a wrap line at each time the maximum character width is reached for a line.

[image: Eclipse preferences]

For example with this setting I can see now the output as expected :

```
000.00
```

But as side effect, I would have a `breakline` in the output at each time my line exceeds the fixed limit.

Comment: That really was the problem. I copied and paste on notepad++ and the zeros were shown. Thanks a lot. This is a weird issue.

Comment: Eclipse has been known to have problems with very long output strings in the console window.

Comment: I have the same issue, large strings are not shown, they seem to be the same color as the console background.  Select the blank (but actually has data) line, paste into notepad, the text is actually there.  Really irritating!